# check if string exist inside a list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
test = [{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test1'},
  {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test2'},
  {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test3'},
  {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4'}]
```

And I want to check if a string exists in this above list.

```
string = "{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4'}"

if string in test:
   print("string exist in list")
else:
   print("string dont exist in list")
```

My variable string ha a string that exist inside the list but Im getting the message "string dont exist in list".

Do you understand why?

Comment: do ``if string in test.values():`` if you want to find your ``string`` value. As of right now, your iterating the dictionary's keys and not the values.

Comment: `if any(d['TopicArn'] == 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4' for d in test):`

Comment: I would use a list of tuples for this purpose instead of a list of dicts.

Comment: test contains a list of dictionaries with key/value pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python `in` function does not work that way. You need to convert your `test` into a list or set of strings first:

```
test2 = set([x['TopicArn'] for x in test])
```

Comment: you need to add if x['TopicArn']==stringvalue

Answer (score 6):

These are the four things in `test`:

```
{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test1'}
{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test2'}
{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test3'}
{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4'}
```

`"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4"` is not one of them, and the `in` comparison doesn't look deeper.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
if any(string in d.values() for d in test):
```

That checks whether the string is in the values of one of the dictionaries in `test`:

```
>>> string = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4"
>>> string in test
False
>>> any(string in d.values() for d in test)
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update my question with your tip, but the issue continues!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but to the casual observer, that string *is* in `test`.  You don't explain what you mean by "is not one of them".

Comment: @techman You're now looking for a string representing the dictionary, but `test` contains dictionaries, not string representations of them. If you remove the outed `""`, it should work.

Comment: @dimo414 Yeah, agree, that's why I added that last part of the explanation then.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of dictionaries, try this:

```
found = False
for adict in test:
    if string in adict.values():
       found = True
if not found:
    print("string dont exist in list")
else:
    print("string in list")
```

It seems what you really want to know is if the string is one of the values in one of the dictionaries in the list.

A more pythonic one-liner was given as a comment:

```
if any(d['TopicArn'] == string for d in test):
    print("string in list")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `dicts` inside the list. 
You have to iterate over the list and check if the string is in the dict values.

```
string = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4"

for d in test:
    if string in d.values():
       print("string exist in list")
    else:
       print("string dont exist in list")
```

If you just ask `if string in test` , it will check if the string `"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4"` in one of the elements in the `list`. That is not True.

Comment: This will print out 4 answers.

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension and compare the values for a pattern match.

```
 test = [{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test1'},
  {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test2'},
  {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test3'},
  {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4'}]

 string = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4'

 result=list(d for d in test if string in d.values())
 print(result)
```

output:

```
 [{'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:700257:test4'}]
```